# Using string for dplyr filter and for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data set which has a list of Person IDs (persons), some linguistic features each individual used, and how many times they used each of them. It would look something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(PID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Feature = c("F2", "F3", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F1", "F3"), Freq = c(2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3))

ids <- data.frame(PID = 1:3, Level = c("low", "mid", "high"))
```

I'm transforming it into a data frame that would have one person per row and the linguistic features as columns:

```
f_freq <- data.frame(ids[1:2], matrix(nrow = nrow(ids), ncol = 3))
f_names <- c("F1", "F2", "F3) 
names(f_freq)[3:5] <- f_names
```

So I want to map the frequency information from the first data frame (df) to the new one (f_freq), and also insert 0 for the features that each individual did not use. I wrote a for-loop for to achieve this purpose:

```
for (h in 1:length(f_names)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(f_freq)) {
        t1 <- filter(df, Feature == f_names[[h]])
        if (f_freq$PID[j] %in% t1$PID) {
            f_freq[j, f_names[[h]]] <- t1[t1$PID == f_freq$ID[j], "Freq"]
        } else {
            out[j, f_names[[h]]] <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

However it just returns NAs. It works when I input each feature name, as below.

```
for (h in 1:length(f_names)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(f_freq)) {
        t1 <- filter(df, Feature == "F1")
        if (f_freq$PID[j] %in% t1$PID) {
            f_freq[j, "F1"] <- t1[t1$PID == f_freq$ID[j], "Freq"]
        } else {
            out[j, "F1"] <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

But I have 35 features in the actual data so I would like to automatize this. I'm not sure why the first loop does not work. If anyone knows how to solve this issue, please let me know!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this without any loop.  Just do a `left_join` with the first dataset 'df' and the subset of columns in 'f_freq' (no need to create "F\d+" columns in the new dataset).  Use `spread` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(df, f_freq[1:2]) %>%             
         spread(Feature, Freq, fill = 0)
#  PID Level F1 F2 F3
#1   1   low  0  2  1
#2   2   mid  3  1  2
#3   3  high  4  0  3
```

If we only need a binary output for the 'F' columns, change the 'Freq' to 1 and do the `spread`

```
left_join(df, f_freq[1:2]) %>%    
     mutate(Freq = 1) %>%
     spread(Feature, Freq, fill = 0)
```

Comment: This works great. I didn't know about the fill argument that's why I used loop. It helps me a great deal. Thank you!